# why interpolation works inside ng-show and not inside ng-click

Tags: angularjs, expression, string-interpolation, ng-show

// template

```
      <div ng-controller="myController">
        <input type="text" ng-model="name">
        <p>{{name}}</p>
        <p>{{10+10}}</p>
        <button type="button" ng-click="{{myFunction()}}">click Me !!</button>

        <p ng-show="{{myFunction()}}">The name is {{ name | uppercase }}</p>

      </div>

// Controller

myApp.controller('myController', function ($scope) {

  $scope.name = 'Ranka';
  $scope.myFunction = function(){
    return true;
  };

});
```

Here it is failing in case of ng-click

> angular.js:14525 Error: [$parse:syntax] Syntax Error: Token '{' invalid key at column 2 of the expression [{{myFunction()}}] starting at [{myFunction()}}].

Comment: Interpolation is not needed for ng-show and it is advised not to trigger events on ng-show, since it will increase your memory usage. Events should be triggered only on things like ng-click,ng-change etc... where you don't need any interpolation as all these are angular directives

Comment: I think it's nice question if the question is related with two way binding in function.

Answer (score 0):

Just use without the expression,

```
<button type="button" ng-click="myFunction()">click Me !!</button>
```

Comment: Yes, I can do that but why I can't do what I trying as ng-click simply require angularjs expression.

Answer (score 0):

`ng-show` and `ng-click` are already an inbuild directive in angularjs. So, we no need to put it in curly braces for these expressions.

Without controller we doing the context in html itself. Use `ng-init` directive use to define as a variable you like and override the variable in `ng-click` as you want

```
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl" ng-init="showName = false;">
 <input type="text" ng-model="name">
        <p>{{name}}</p>
        <p>{{10+10}}</p>
        <button type="button" ng-click="showName = true">click Me !!</button>

        <p ng-show="showName">The name is {{ name | uppercase }}</p>
</div>
```

controller:

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);

    function MyCtrl($scope) {
       $scope.name = 'Ranka';
    }
```

[**Working Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/ADukg/12878/)

Comment: sorry but my question is why can't we add interpolation in expression if we are allowed to do it inside ng-show attribute?

Comment: For anything which we need one way binding we will use curly braces(interpolation). But for ng-show directive its by nature referring the model and hence not required interpolation over there.

Answer (score 0):

try this simple way

```
    <button type="button" ng-click="{{ myFunction(); isShow = false}}">click Me !!</button>

    <p ng-show="{{isShow}}">The name is {{ name | uppercase }}</p>
```

and controller should be like,

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);
       function MyCtrl($scope) {
       $scope.isShow= true;
       $scope.name = 'hallow world!';
    }
```